# Which Metric For Network Load Times?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, developer, network

In F12 Developer Tools in IE, when measuring load times for SharePoint in O365, which metric should be used to calculate the full length of time it takes for a page to load?

On the network tab in Developer Tools under the Timing tab if I use the load (event) then there are still asynchronous operations happening after this event which sometimes make the page seem it has not fully loaded.  The full times seem to represent the length of time that the recording has been ongoing.

The SPRequestDuration in the Response Header represents the time for processing on the server and does not represent full page load time.

[image: Example Load Times]